# Install ffmpeg-light with cabal

Tags: c, haskell, ffmpeg, installation, cabal

I want to install the ffmpeg-light library from hackage via cabal on Windows 10 (64 bit). So I downloaded ffmpeg and extracted it to C:\FFmpeg.

At first pkg-config was complaining that it could not find various packages. I solved this problem with .pc files.

When I tried to use the command: `cabal install ffmpeg-light` cabal complained about missing C-libraries, being exactly those for which I created the .pc files.

Then I tried the command: `cabal install ffmpeg-light --extra-lib-dirs=C:\FFmpeg\lib`. Now I have a different error message, which says:

```
Enums.hsc:7:32: fatal error: libavcodec/avcodec.h: No such file or directory
```

**Edit:**
Then I tried the following command:

```
cabal install ffmpeg-light --extra-lib-dirs=C:\FFmpeg\lib \
                           --extra-include-dirs=C:\FFmpeg\include
```

Now first the compiler gives some warnings about deprecated functions in ffmpeg and redundant imports in ffmpeg-light, but compiles 11 of 11. But the build is still not successfull.

```
In-place registering ffmpeg-light-0.11.1...
setup-Simple-Cabal-1.22.5.0-x86_64-windows-ghc-7.10.3.exe:
'C:\Haskell\bin\ghc-pkg.exe' exited with an error:
ffmpeg-light-0.11.1: Warning: haddock-interfaces:
C:\Users\HOLEYC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cabal-tmp-2824\ffmpeg-light-0.11.1\dist\doc\html\ffmpeg-light\ffmpeg-light.haddock
doesn't exist or isn't a file
ffmpeg-light-0.11.1: Warning: haddock-html:
C:\Users\HOLEYC~1\AppData\Local\Temp\cabal-tmp-2824\ffmpeg-light-0.11.1\dist\doc\html\ffmpeg-light
doesn't exist or isn't a directory
ffmpeg-light-0.11.1: library-dirs: C:FFmpeglib is a relative path which makes
no sense (as there is nothing for it to be relative to). You can make paths
relative to the package database itself by using ${pkgroot}. (use --force to
override)
ffmpeg-light-0.11.1: include-dirs: C:FFmpeginclude is a relative path which
makes no sense (as there is nothing for it to be relative to). You can make
paths relative to the package database itself by using ${pkgroot}. (use
--force to override)
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
ffmpeg-light-0.11.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

**Some additional information:**

```
cabal version: cabal-install version 1.22.6.0
using version 1.22.5.0 of the Cabal library
gcc version of my installed Haskell platform: 5.2.0
```

Example .pc file I used for pkg-config:

```
Name: libavcodec
Description: Library for ffmpeg
Version: 57
Cflags: -IC:\FFmpeg\include
Libs: -LC:\FFmpeg\lib -llibavcodec
```

Comment: You need `--extra-include-dirs` to tell ghc where to find the header file.

Comment: @Thomas M. DuBuisson: Thanks, that got me a step further. Edited my question.

Comment: I think you need to escape your slashes.  Ex: `--extra-include-dirs=C:\\FFmpeg\\include`

Answer (score 0):

OK. I figured it out. The --ghc-pkg-options="--force" option was needed.
`cabal install ffmpeg-light --extra-lib-dirs=C:\FFmpeg\lib --extra-include-dirs=C:\FFmpeg\include --ghc-pkg-options="--force"`